# Java: ¿Por qué no completa el flujo o se salta el if?

Tags: java

Quiero que el siguiente método al rellenar los 2 campos variantData y serviceData realice todo el flujo. Es decir, de de baja el variant y de alta el service. Según está ahora me da de baja el variant pero de ahí me salta al error genérico. También me está pasando que si dejo vacío el variant o el service hace caso omiso del if y entra al flujo cuando no debería (ya que ambos campos deben estár rellenos). ¿Qué está fallando? La idea es que si uno de los 2 campos (variant o service) no están rellenos lance el mensaje de error del if de que son obligatorios y si ambos están rellenos haga todo el flujo que hay después del else. Si quito el if y el try funciona pero necesito hacer esa comprobación y parar el flujo si no están rellenos. Gracias.

```
public final String modifyData() {
    try {
        if (variantData == null || serviceData == null) {
            message = "Fields variant and service are mandatory.";
            return changeResponse();
        } else {
            ParamGetJobsByNumber param = new ParamGetJobsByNumber();
            param.setNumber(variantData);
            ResultGetJobsByNumber resultJobsByVariant = getAgentSystem().fetchJobsByNumber(param);

            ParamProcedureDeleteAssignedJobList paramDeleteJobs = new ParamProcedureDeleteAssignedJobList();
            paramDeleteJobs.setJobList(resultJobsByVariant.getJobCodes());
            paramDeleteJobs.setNumber(Long.valueOf(variantData));
            getAgentSystem().executeDeleteAssignedJobList(paramDeleteJobs);

            param.setNumber(serviceData);
            ResultGetJobsByNumber resultJobsByService = getAgentSystem().fetchJobsByNumber(param);

            List<String> jobsFromVariant = resultJobsByVariant.getJobCodes();
            List<String> jobsFromService = resultJobsByService.getJobCodes();

            List<String> jobsToAdd = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String jobCodeFromVariant : jobsFromVariant) {
                if (!jobsFromService.contains(jobCodeFromVariant)) {
                    jobsToAdd.add(jobCodeFromVariant);
                }
            }

            ParamProcedureAddAssignedJobList paramAddJobs = new ParamProcedureAddAssignedJobList();
            paramAddJobs.setJobList(jobsToAdd);
            paramAddJobs.setNumber(Long.valueOf(serviceData));
            getAgentSystem().executeAddAssignedJobList(paramAddJobs);

            message = "Modification completed successfully";
            return changeResponse();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        message = e.getMessage();
        return changeResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Generic application error: " + e.getMessage();
        return changeResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Intentaste imprimir el valor de variantData y serviceData antes de entrar al if? Trata de realizar una traza del estado de tus variables durante la ejecucion de tu programa.

Comment: ¿Qué tal si los string son cadenas vacías `""`? No parece que tu código lo tenga en cuenta

Comment: Hola Basilea, creo que deberías usar **variantData.equals( "" ) || serviceData.equals( "" )**...